# Domain with directories or new domains?

Tags: seo, dns

what is better, a domain with subdirectories or whole new domains for those directories?

I have a website divided by 12 directories which are the main purpose of the website
like:
  example.com/subject1
  example.com/subject2

I was wondering what is better for me, new domains for subject1 and subject2, like subject1.com and subject2.dom etc or keep it as folders?

or new domains that points to the main domain /directory?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: What's your standard for better?  Better for SEO?  Better for organizational?  Better for martians to figure out how to use your website?

Comment: Better for SEO and if it is better for marketting or not

Comment: I don't know exactly how it works, but remember cookies, which are tied to domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends if you want to keep them as separate entities or not, which would depend on your goals.

subject1.example.com and subject2.example.com both point to example.com, so any marketing efforts all serve to build up example.com, but you only have one site.

If you want to build them up as separate entities, then subject1.com and subject2.com are the way to go, but that means your marketing efforts are split between them.

On the back end, it's no more difficult to point the directories on your space to separate domains than it is to point them to subdomains of one common domain.

Comment: its about the same main subject, but for complete different organizaiotions, like ecommerce.com/amazon and ecommerce.com/compusa for example... its the same kind of thing, but they are different, my problem is about advertising, if it is better for me to show big numbers of one site or little less numbers for whole 12 websites.

Comment: If the main subject is the same and your target visitors will browse the whole site, then just keep it under one domain.  It will strengthen your ecommerce.com brand (that part of the domain is most memorable), and will likely be easier overall.